# Retrieve children codes that match criteria in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables (ChildrenRecordsTable and AllRecordsTable) in SQL server 2008

```
ChildrenRecordsTable (code varchar(20)) --
AllRecordsTable (code varchar(20), flag smallint) 

ChildrenRecordsTable Data  (Subset of the whole set) --
235,
2350 (Child of 235),
2351 (child of 235),
23500 (child of 2350),
23501 (child of 2350),
235011100 (child of 23501110),
100,
1001 (child of 100),
1002 (child of 100),
1003 (child of 100),
10010 (child of 1001),
10011 (child of 1001),
100111 (child of 10011),
100100 (child of 10010),
1001000 (child of 100100),

AllRecordsTable Data (Whole set) --
235,
2350 (Child of 235),
2351 (child of 235),
2352 (child of 235),
.....
23500 (child of 2350),
23501 (child of 2350),
....
235011100 (child of 23501110),
....
100,
1001 (child of 100),
1002 (child of 100),
....
10010 (child of 1001),
10011 (child of 1001),
100111 (child of 10011),
....
100100 (child of 10010),
1001000 (child of 100100),
....
```

I would like to write a query to get the children code from ChildrenRecordsTable
where all their parents in the AllRecordsTable flag > 3

I wrote a while loop that goes over the children table and check all the parents records where flag > 3. The query is running very slow. Is it possible to write it differently?

The SQL logic below:
1-Retrieve all parents for every record in ChildrenRecordsTable that match criteria flag < 3
2-Compare the count of the number of records with the number of parents count
3- If they are not equal remove the child records
4- Repeat the process for every child record in table ChildrenRecordsTable

```
 declare @TableID varchar(20)
 declare @ChildrenFGCodes table (Id varchar(20) NOT NULL)
 declare @ParentFGCs table (Id varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED)
 declare @ParentCount smallint
 declare @counter smallint
 declare @numRecord smallint

 insert into @ChildrenFGCodes SELECT FunctionalGroupCode from #ChildrenRecordsTable 

 while exists (select * from @ChildrenFGCodes)
        begin
              select top 1 @TableID = Id
              from @ChildrenFGCodes
              order by Id asc

              SET @ParentCount = LEN(@TableID) - 4
              SET @counter = 1
              WHILE @counter <= @ParentCount
                BEGIN
                    insert into @ParentFGCs values (LEFT(@TableID, LEN(@TableID) - @counter))
                    SET @counter = @counter + 1
                END                 

                SELECT @numRecord=COUNT(*)   
                    from AllRecordsTable  a, @ParentFGCs b
                    where ((a.code = b.Id) AND (a.flag < 3))

              IF @numRecord <> @ParentCount
                    BEGIN
                      delete #ChildrenRecordsTable  where Code = @TableID
                    END                 
              delete FROM @ParentFGCs
              delete @ChildrenFGCodes where Id = @TableID 
        end
```

Comment: heard about CTE? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

Comment: also helpful if you post the raw data and table structure

Comment: raw data and table structure included in the post

Comment: okay... goodluck

Comment: @ibrahim Please post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` scripts for your sample data.